# Is there any way to programmatically launch an app so that it starts in a snapped view?

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-8

I want to launch a URL in my JavaScript app for Windows 8 using `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync`, but I want it to start in a snapped view. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by 'already pinned'?  What URI are you launching, one for which the scheme is registered to another Windows Store app?

Comment: Yes -- most likely a URL. I want to keep my app open while launching the appropriate app pinned.

Comment: by pinned do you mean "snapped"? so it appears side by side? pinned typically implies an icon on the start bar (non relevant for Windows 8 Store apps) or perhaps by extension a tile on the Start Screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't start an app in snapped more or cause another to be started in that mode. One key thing to note is that a snapped view might not even be possible depending on the orientation or resolution of the screen.  Additionally, with the philosophy of the user being in charge, it should be his/her choice to move to snapped mode.

You can programmatically move out of snapped mode (to fill mode) via [TryUnsnap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryunsnap.aspx); however, [the guidelines do state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465371.aspx)

> Put the user in control. Don't programmatically unsnap your app to get
> the user's attention. Unsnapping should be reserved only for
> situations when the user tries to use a feature that is not available
> in the snapped state. If your app has snapped views for all pages in
> the app, you shouldn't need to programmatically unsnap at all.
>
> Don't add UI controls to programmatically unsnap your app. The splitter
> between the apps is always present and lets the user unsnap whenever
> they want to.