# How to start a MetroApp directly in Snapped mode?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force WinRT app to snapped view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907058/force-winrt-app-to-snapped-view)

Is it possible to start a MetroApp directly in snapped mode?

I want to call another App by Protocol, an the App should open in Snapped mode.

The call to the App by Protocol is not a problem, it works fine, but the App opens in Fullscreen or Main-Content Mode.

I have'nt found any configuration to say "start on Sidebar".

Please Help!

Comment: Not possible, AFAIK. Putting an app in Snapped mode is a user choice.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737986/is-there-any-way-to-programmatically-launch-an-app-so-that-it-starts-in-a-snappe

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668721/how-to-snap-app-programmatically-in-windows-8

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907058/force-winrt-app-to-snapped-view

Answer (score 3):

As of now the answer is no. Since the snapped mode functionality depends on the user , you cant skip it / restrict it using code ,  Hope MS might provide this feature in further .

As @Hermit Dave mentioned unsnapping is possible.

Comment: Kind of strange that snapping is purely a user choice but unsnapping is not.

Comment: I don't want developers arranging my apps for me. I see your case, and I realize it is fine - but it's also an edge case. If this were possible, developers would likely abuse it, not use it properly like you. I concede your point, but I like how it is, too.

Answer (score 1):

The ApplicationView class that i have come across only exposes TryUnsnap and Value (current view value) which is used to request a change from snapped to unsnapped view.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701658.aspx

I dont think what you want is possible.